# Memory-wise, is it better to store a long non-dynamic string as a single string object or to have the program build it out of it's repetitive parts?

Tags: c#, string, memory-management

This is a bit of an odd question and **more of a though experiment that anything I need**, but I'm still curious about the answer: If I have a string that I know ahead of time will never change but is (mostly) made up of repetitive parts, would it be better to have said string as just a single string object, get called when needed, and be done with it - or should I break the string up into smaller strings that represent the repeated parts and concatenate them when needed?

Let me use an example:  Let's say we have a naive programmer who wants to create a regular expression for validating IP Addresses (in other words, I know this regular expression won't work as intended, but it helps show what I mean by repetitive parts and saves me a bit of typing for the second part of the example).  So he writes this function:

```
 private bool isValidIP(string ip)
 {
   Regex checkIP = new Regex("\\d\\d?\\d?\\.\\d\\d?\\d?\\.\\d\\d?\\d?\\.\\d\\d?\\d?");
   return checkIP.IsMatch(ip);
 }
```

Now our young programmer notices that he has "\d", "\d?", and "\." just repeated a few times.  This gives him an idea that he could both save some storage space and help remind himself what this means for later.  So he remakes the function:

```
 private bool isValidIP(string ip)
 {
   string escape = "\\";
   string digi = "d";
   string digit = escape + digi;
   string possibleDigit = digit + '?';
   string IpByte = digit + possibleDigit + possibleDigit;
   string period = escape + '.';
   Regex checkIP = new Regex(IpByte + period + IpByte + period + IpByte + period + IpByte);
   return checkIP.IsMatch(ip);
 }
```

The first method is simple.  It just stores 38 chars in the program's instructions, which are just read into memory each time the function is called.
The second method stores (I suspect) two 1 length strings and two chars into the program's instructions as well as all of the calls to concatenate those four into different orders.  This creates at least 8 strings in memory when the program is called (the six named strings, a temporary string for the first four parts of the regex, and then the final string created from the previous string + the three strings of the regex).  This second method also happens to help explain what the regex is looking for - though not what the final regex would look like.  It could also help with refactoring, say if our hypothetical programmer realizes that his current regex will allow for more than just 0-255 in the IP Address, and the constitute parts can be changed without having to find every single item that would need to be fixed.

Again, which method would be better?  Would it just be as simple as a trade-off between program size vs. memory usage?  **Of course, with something as simple as this, the trade-off is negligible at best, but what about a much larger, more complex string?**

Oh, yes, and a much better regex for IP Addresses would be:

```
 ^(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|[01]?\\d\\d?)(\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\\d|[01]?\\d\\d?)){3}$
```

Wouldn't work as well as an example, would it?

Comment: Unless you're doing billions of these, this is most likely preemptive optimization, as speed and memory in this case is most likely negligible.  Based on this assumption, it would be best to have a re-usable, well definied utilities class (or extension method) to do this work.

Comment: I agree with @Erik Philips. Also, please never ask if one piece of code is **better** than another. Some code can **run faster** than other code, some code can be **written faster** than other code, some code can be **read more easily** than other code, some code **takes less space** than other code and many more.

Comment: @ChrisHaas he limited it to memory consumption in the question.

Comment: @Joshua Drake, he mentions memory but also refactoring.

Comment: @ChrisHaas apologies, missed that part. Maybe this should be two questions.

Comment: @Erik Philips Yes, I realize this is micro-optimization for this exact case, but what about much more complicated strings, say a large html table (for whatever odd reason someone would want an html table string in a C# program)?  My question is about something like that: a huge string that is made up of repetitious parts.

Comment: @Chris Haas I kept using 'better' because if I had chosen one type of comparison, there would be a clear answer.  Of the ones you gave: first, usually first (depends on the final string), depends on your familiarity with what the final string stands for, usually first.

Comment: You are like a billionaire counting pennies. You have two billion bytes, at least, of address space at your disposal and you are trying to optimize storage of about thirty of them, by building a machine that will itself consume hundreds and hundreds of bytes of code. **Spend your time solving problems that you actually have.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first is by far the better option.  Here's why

1. It's clearer.
2. It's cheaper. Any time you declare a new object it's an "expensive" process.  You have to make space for it on the heap (well for strings at least).  Yes, you could in theory be saving a byte or so, but your spending a lot more time (probably, I haven't tested it) going through and allocating space for each string, additional memory instructions etc.  Not to mention the fact that remember, you also have to factor in the use of the GC.  You keep allocating strings and eventually you are going to have to contend with it taking up process ticks also. You really want to hit on optimization, I can easily tell this code isn't as efficient as it could be.  There are no constants for one thing, which means that you are possibly creating more objects than you need instead of letting the compiler optimize for strings that don't need to change.  This leads me to think, that as a person reviewing this code, I need to take a much closer look at what is going to see what is going on and figure out if something is wrong.
3. It's clearer (yes, I said this again).  You want to do an academic pursuit to see how efficient you can make it.  That's cool.  I get that.  I do it myself.  It's fun.  I NEVER let that slip into production code.  I don't care about losing a tick, I care about having a bug in production, and I care about if other programmers can understand what my code does.  Reading someone else's code is hard enough, I don't want to add the extra task of them having to try and figure out which micro-optimization I put in and what happens if they "nudge" the wrong piece of code.
4. You hit on another point. What if the original regex is wrong.  Google will tell you this problem has been solved.  You can Google another regex that's right and has been tested.  You can't Google "What's wrong with my code."  You can post it on SO sure, but that means that someone else has to get involved and look through it.

Here's how to make the first example win the horse race easily:

```
 Regex checkIP = new Regex(
   "\\d\\d?\\d?\\.\\d\\d?\\d?\\.\\d\\d?\\d?\\.\\d\\d?\\d?");

 private bool isValidIP(string ip)
 {
   return checkIP.IsMatch(ip);
 }
```

Declare once, reuse over and over.  If you are taking the time to recreate the regex dynamically to save a few, don't get to do that. Technically you could do that and still only create the object once, but that is a lot more work than say, moving it to a class level variable.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that in the second example since all the strings are local, written to exactly once at initialization, and stuck together in a constant manner, the compiler probably turns that mess into the first example anyway.

Comment: And finally, changing the constructor call to `new Regex(/* expr */, RegexOptions.Compiled)` wins the horse race handily.

Answer (score 2):

You're effectively attempting to game the compiler here and implement your own string compression.  For the kinds of string literals you're describing, it seems like your savings will be mere tens of bytes shaved off of the compiled binary, which due to memory alignment may not even be realized.  In exchange for these few bytes of saved space, this approach adds code complexity and runtime overhead, not to mention difficulty in debugging.

Storage is cheap.  Why make your life (and the lives of your coworkers) harder?  Keep your code simple, clear, and evident - you'll thank yourself later.

Answer (score 0):

The second is worse off in memory consumption, as every time you concatenate two strings you've got three in memory.

Although the compiler started handling some instances of string constants by creating a `StringBuilder` for you, I'd still vote for the first one being less memory intensive, because if the system does create the `StringBuilder` for you, you are going to have the overhead for that, and if it doesn't see the first paragraph...

I am now curious how compiling the RegEx would effect the memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Savings here are illusionary and splitting this string up is a big overshot. Saving insignificant amount of memory and complicating so simple code is just pointless. You will not see any savings but next person to maintain that code will spend 10x more time understanding it.

Strings are immutable so if your string never/rarely changes keep it in one piece. Intense string concatenations give garbage collector additional strain.

Unless your strings and sub-strings are big and you could save at least kilobytes, do not spend your time and effort on such optimizations.